# gcloud app deploy failed due to deleted staging bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I mis-deleted a bucket named `staging.MYPROJ.appinfo.com` on google cloud storage console, and now I can't deploy my AppEngine app.

When I run `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`, here is the error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Insufficient permissions to create Google Cloud Storage bucket.
Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "resourceName": "staging.MYPROJ.appspot.com",
      "resourceType": "cloud storage bucket"
    }
  ]
]
```

So here are my questions:

1. Why a deleted staging bucket prevents me from deploying the app?
2. How to deploy my app now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in `gcloud app deploy --help`:

> The Google Cloud Storage bucket used to stage files associated with
>   the deployment. If this argument is not specified, the application's
>   default code bucket is used.

So, we need a bucket to stage files.

I end up creating a new bucket and running this command:

```
$ gcloud app deploy app.yaml --bucket=gs://my_new_bucket
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76826942/309917), you can repair your app and recreate the mis-deleted staging bucket with `gcloud beta app repair`