# gcloud app deploy complains about missing staging bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I've been used since months or years to delete `staging` and `artifacts` buckets after `gcloud app deploy` command to save on billing costs. These temporary files rest in there forever and I get billed for it.

It always worked until this morning when I got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) B instance [staging.my-proj-id.appspot.com] not found: The specified bucket does not exist.
```

I tried to recreate the bucket but I'm not allowed since I'm supposed to prove ownership of the `staging.my-proj-id.appspot.com` domain — which I have not.

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 You must verify site or domain ownership
```

I'm stuck and I have important changes to deploy

Comment: It might be a change in the Google Cloud platform. Ask the support to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere, I am not entitled to raise issues with the support apart from billing issues...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed this running [this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/repair):

```
gcloud beta app repair
```

I got this direction trying to indicate my own staging bucket with

```
gcloud app deploy --bucket=gs://my-own-staging-bucket
```

like [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49770970/309917) which returned:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [5] Staging bucket staging.my-proj-id.appspot.com is not available. Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair to repair your app.
```

Comment: This is interesting & also seems like a change in behavior. Like you, used to delete the staging bucket after a deploy and never had a problem. Later stopped just cos it felt like a hassle for just a few cents.

Comment: This is a good answer. Advice to others. Do **not** delete the managed buckets and artifacts that Google uses for your project. Leave those objects alone. If you are testing, create a new project and then delete the project when you are finished to minimize billing.  The pain is just not worth saving a few pennies/dimes.

Comment: Thanks worked for me!  I did indeed delete the staging buckets before as it had not been touched for years and I thought it was just extra space being used.  Running `gcloud beta app repair` resolved the issue and I see the bucket back now.